# MySQL SELECT from shell doens't show all charecters in the column without using \G

Tags: mysql, linux, database, text

I am running SELECT statement on a table in mysql but am getting the following output:

```
mysql> SELECT col_1 as a, col_2 as b FROM Person_Names LIMIT 10;
+----------+---------------------------------+
| a        | b                               |
+----------+---------------------------------+
                |a marschoff
            |ä¸‰åƒä»£ éµœä¸¹è°·
                |hard pippes
                |ko unoshima
         | | beatriz setuain mendia
             |eth t clingenpeel
             |ichael k budinski
                     |a
                  | æ¾¤é‡Ž
 |000122D5 | erasmus universiteit rotterdam
+----------+---------------------------------+
```

This output doesn't look correct as the data was successfully loaded into the table. I can check this when I run the same command with the `\G` option and get the correct result.

```
mysql> SELECT col_1 as a, col_2 as b FROM Person_Names LIMIT 10\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
a: 00001E95
b: maria marschoff
*************************** 2. row ***************************
a: 00002616
b: ä¸‰åƒä»£ éµœä¸¹è°·
*************************** 3. row ***************************
a: 00002EE0
b: reinhard pippes
*************************** 4. row ***************************
a: 00003C1F
b: masako unoshima
*************************** 5. row ***************************
a: 00004C78
b: beatriz setuain mendia
*************************** 6. row ***************************
a: 000059A6
b: beth t clingenpeel
*************************** 7. row ***************************
a: 00008EB6
b: michael k budinski
*************************** 8. row ***************************
a: 0000F24F
b: jim seroka
*************************** 9. row ***************************
a: 00010096
b: é †å½¦ æ¾¤é‡Ž
*************************** 10. row ***************************
a: 000122D5
b: erasmus universiteit rotterdam
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The data was loaded form files into the tables. This is how the data looks in the file:

```
00001E95        maria marschoff
00002616        ä¸‰åƒä»£ éµœä¸¹è°·
00002EE0        reinhard pippes
00003C1F        masako unoshima
00004C78        beatriz setuain mendia
000059A6        beth t clingenpeel
00008EB6        michael k budinski
0000F24F        jim seroka
00010096        é †å½¦ æ¾¤é‡Ž
000122D5        erasmus universiteit rotterdam
```

And this was the command used for loading it:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "Persons.txt" INTO TABLE Person_Names FIELDS TERMINATED BY "\t";
```

And this is the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `Person_Names` (
`col_1` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL  COMMENT 'Col ID',
`col_2` VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Col name'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT 'Person_Names';
```

Has anyone else also experienced this issue? Is there a way to fix this in the DB or do I have to re-create the tables. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: if any of those randomish/garbage fields contain characters that are terminal control sequences, they can get printed  out as-is and affect your terminal.

Comment: Thanks @MarcB, what can be a SQL specific way to load this kind of data. I don't mind losing rows which has that non-ascii data. Also I know, I can pre-process the whole data and then load it, but because of the size of the data (>80G), I would prefer a method which can be done in the DB or while doing the `LOAD DATA` operation

Comment: are you sure they weren't loaded properly? it could just be a display-upon-retrieval problem...